# Angular include CDN in component usage

Tags: angular, typescript

I have CDN URL and I want to use it inside of the Component TypeScript file.

What would be the "right" way of dealing with CDN's in Angular 2 and greater versions?

Comment: Assuming you're using Angular CLI, you'd need to add it to the `scripts` array of your `Angular.json` file

Comment: Does the library have a npm package

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want users to retrieve the js/css files from a CDN, you need to include these files in your index.html. Example with momentjs (Note: this is just an example, momentjs can be installed via npm in your project)

**index.html**

```
<!-- get script from CDN -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js" />
```

Then, to use the the script in your component, you need to manually declare the exported variables / functions to avoid TS compilation errors

**component.ts**

```
declare let moment: any; //declare moment

//use moment
moment().format(....);
```

**Note**: some libraries have types that you can use instead, instead of using `any`. You can get these types from the @types repository

Comment: is there a way to do this without using the index.html? asking because I want to include a cdn into my library?

Comment: This approach does not work when I change any value in my cdn component .,I need to manually build my application again to get the update.,is there anyway I can get the update without manual build.,

Comment: also doesn't work with async  CDN load...

Comment: When using this approach for the PhotoSwipeLightbox , 

I got an error :  ERROR ReferenceError: "PhotoSwipeLightbox is not defined" 

After declaring, I instantiate :     this.lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox

Comment: if there is multiple CDN we have then? what is the best way to do that?