# how can i add an url link in script part of angular cli project

Tags: angular

```
"scripts": [
      "@import http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.32/jquery.form.js",
      "plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "@import https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.min.js",
      "./js/script.js"
]
```

is what i did right ? i need to import those link there but i don't know how to do it this 
error : 
Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 92% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\ms-front-web@import http:\cdnjs.cloudflare.com\ajax\libs\jquery.form\3.32\jquery.form.js '

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adding cdn urls in scripts is not allowed, instead you should include the js/css files from CDN in your index.html.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.32/jquery.form.js" />
```

Some of the links for your reference and how to use it. [Angular include CDN in component usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484076/angular-include-cdn-in-component-usage)
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2280
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6887

I would recommend to install your packages as module using npm and include it in your scripts.

Example: 
`npm install bootstrap --save-dev`
`npm install jquery --save-dev`
then

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
```