# Consume angular service function via cdn

Tags: angular

I have a very light weight angular library that has a service with simple calculate functions. This library get linked as npm module with 10+ micro front end angular apps. Everytime I make a minor change the way calculate function implemented, we end up rebuilding all 10+ angular apps use this lib. So, instead of linking it as npm lib at compile time, we are thinking to distribute this lib as pure js lib via cdn at runtime and use it by import. My question is:

(1) How to compile this angular lib with service as a pure js lib.

(2) Is there anything special need to be done at consuming angular apps to use this lib via cdn import.

Thanks, Sri.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you're able to create JS libraries with the angular CLI but I'm not sure if just convert all to JS or use this JS service as an import and then use the service in TS. Might want to read a bit of this [Build JavaScript libraries with the Angular CLI](https://coryrylan.com/blog/build-javascript-libraries-with-the-angular-cli)

For your second question, it's completely possible. Just check, [Angular include CDN in component usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484076/angular-include-cdn-in-component-usage/51534969) or [Loading External Libraries from CDN in Angular Application](https://www.ngdevelop.tech/loading-external-libraries-from-cdn-in-angular-application/)